# The easiest way to test ARM specific codes on windows

Tags: visual-c++, arm, emulation, simd

I would like to write an ARM SIMD computer vision code on an intel based windows machine. 
I would like to know what are the different options for doing that. I know for example that I can run a rasperrpi-emulator on windows, but that's really slow, and not productive. 
I hope if for example there is an IDE like Visuatl C++ that compiles code for ARM and test it like I'm exactly on an ARM platform without buying a real ARM board CPU.

Is it the only way to achieve that to buy an ARM based board ?

If I'm going to use an Emulator like QEMU, is there a faster or elegant way to develop computer vision software on it ?

I'm targeting ARM11 CPUs, that are quad-cores,..etc. Not the old ARM Architecture like M Series or ARM7.

Comment: I think you might be a bit confused with your ARM versions here.  ARM11 is an ARMv6 architecture device that preceded the Cortex-A and Cortex-M series (ARMv7).   You still find ARM11 devices in what are euphemistically called 'landfill Android' phones - and the Raspberry Pi.  ARMv6 doesn't have SIMD unit.  By the sounds of it, you want a CortexA-series device - of which there are plenty. The Cortex-M architecture is targeted at lower-speed applications, and turns up in micro-controllers - and as IO coprocessors in ARM SoCs.

Comment: FYI, the SSE equivalent on ARM is called NEON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By far, your best bet in terms of shortening your test-debug-compile cycle will be buying an ARM board and just programming natively on it or will a cross-compiler.  I have had good luck with Gumstix, which generally are able to take a Linux distro pretty easily.  From there, you have all of your GNU tools and you can just program directly on it.

Comment: Probably also worth pointing out that whilst there are cross compilers build for Windows,  you might be better off with Linux - if only because this is what your target is likely to be running.

Answer (score 1):

Answer depends on what you really have as "ARM SIMD" code **baseline**. Normally ARM SIMD = NEON SIMD extensions.

*If this is the case* and your NEON codebase is written using NEON intrinsics, 
then you can try recently introduced "**automated porting NEON -> SSE solution**", posted by Intel [here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2012/12/12/from-arm-neon-to-intel-mmxsse-automatic-porting-solution-tips-and-tricks).

Looks like easy to use: just include NEONtoSSE.h to your code and re-compile (I expect various C/C++ compilers compatibility).

Comment: No I just want to test ARM Neon intrinsics in windows platform.